# Can you apply the css rule `content` to child elements?

Tags: css

Can you apply the ccs rule content to child elements?

css :

```
a:link:before, a:visited:before{
    content: " "attr(href)" ";
}
```

html :

```
<a href="/home">Home</a>
```

Result :

```
 -------------
|    /home    |
|    Home     |
 -------------
```

However I would like to do the following:

html :

```
<a href="/home"><span>home</span></a>
```

With the previous css the `href` value would appear before the `span`.

**Is it possible to make it appear in the `span`?**

I've tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c9UmJ/2/). It's for a sitemap.

Comment: A little nitpick: none of this is new in CSS3. Not the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements, not the `attr()` function, not the `content` property. All are part of CSS2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

To make generated content render inside the `span`, you need `a:link span:before`.

Unfortunately, in that case, `content: " "attr(href)" ";` will no longer work, because the `a` element is no longer the subject of the selector - the `span` is, and the `span` does not have the `href` attribute.

Comment: So even though the targeted element is a child, this would fall into a  css no compatible parent situation? (i.e. parent selectors don't work in css)

Comment: This wouldn't be possible even with a [parent selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/). What you need is (the nonexistent) `content: parent.attr(href)`, as in @c-smile's answer.

Comment: If you *really* want to use CSS and not jQuery and you don't mind duplicating the `href` (in a safe+valid but unsemantic way), you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/c9UmJ/3/. Yeah, my first answer sucked :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because `attr(...)` works only for the element itself but you actually need something like this:

```
a:link > span:before { content: " "parent.attr(href)" "; }
```

But no such thing as `parent.attr()` in CSS.